# How to git log a remote branch without fetching repository

Tags: git, shell

I need to delete a branch on remote repository which is older and 30 days and its very slow to current process

currently

```
git fetch --depth=1

list=$(git ls-remote --heads git@xxxxx.xx.xx.com:/xxx/xxx-xxx/xxx-xxx-a | grep ci)

for i in $list
do
    if [ -n "$(git log -1 --before='30 days ago' -s origin/$i)" ]; then
    git push origin :$i
    echo " Deleted Branch $i"
    fi
done
```

Comment: I am confused about how your script actually works. According to the git man pages, `git fetch --depth` is for shallow clones, but shallow clones can't be pushed from!

Comment: @RobinGreen I'm not sure that matters here as he would simply be deleting references (no actual transfer of object would need to happen at delete time).  So a shallow clone may work.  That said, if the branch tips are behind, you may still end up transferring quite a bit of data.

Comment: why do you need `git ls-remote`?  fetching should get you all the remote branches.  also it looks like your `git log` is fetching the first commit older than 30 days, NOT testing that the first commit is 30 days old

Answer (score 2):

While `origin/XY` is called a remote branch, it is still a branch that exists in your local repository. It is just called remote branch because it represents the state the remote repository’s branch of that names is in. So it is indeed a normal pointer that points to a commit history that should be completely contained in your local repository.

While `git ls-remote` may be able to tell you which branch exist on the remote repository, that will not mean that you will have necessary data in your local repository to display any information about it. Remember that all operations (except actual transfer operations like fetch/pull and push) are executed locally.

So to be able to call `git log`, you will need to get all the commit objects that are part of the history of that remote branch. The way you do that is by simply using `git fetch` to fetch the objects from the remote repository. There is no other way to do this.

So if you want to access the log of a remote repository, you will have to clone it to have the information available locally.

The other option would be to execute this on the remote computer itself, or to have e.g. a web interface that will display a log to you (gitweb, GitHub etc.).